# Batch To delete all files in a folder that do not contain a phrase

Tags: batch-file, delete-file

I need a batch files to delete more files which does not contain within them a series of words.

Path Root of folder

> D:\Programmi Installati\Openvpn Portable\data\log

File have different name but end with .log

```
123.log
abc.log
home.log
```

I need to delete all files that NOT contain in the source "Successfully Connected", the files have many lines.

This bat file must read inside the files .log saved in the folder and delete all files that NOT contain the phrase "Successfully Connected",

Note: All files have several lines of text inside them and contains simple text.

Comment: Just curious does it have to be a batch file? There are likely easier solutions via grep, Python, etc.

Comment: @scunliffe - batch files are almost 100% portable between all windows machines. Usually they are fast .Does not require third party software installed.With little investment in learning them they can be pretty powerful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
pushd "D:\Programmi Installati\Openvpn Portable\data\log"
for %%# in (*.log) do (

  find /i "Succefully Connected" "%%~f#" >nu 2>nul||(
    del /q /f "%%~f#" >nul 2>nul
  ) 

)
popd
```

Comment: Hi thanks for solution but i need to specify the path (i write in my post my path), where i can add the path (my path have some spaces)?

Comment: Working like a charms, thanks. Need only to edit "nu 2>nul" -> "nul 2>nul"